# How to consume data from API WCF service from different server and load data into combo-box

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I might have asked this question previously but am not getting it right. I have a drop-down control which i want to consume the data from WCF web service from different project/server. I wrote a small console app to consume data and it works fine. On my controller i have consume data from API and then pass it to my view and that works fine. however, that's not the requirements, i have to load all the combo-box using ajax call to make things easier.

here is my working code: I have hardcoded the Id and boolen type

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult SearchReports()
    {

        string jsonReq = "http://localhost:50000/Administration.svc/GetAllRoles/17d7b719-7524-4297-a20d-6a6260966aad/true";
        string jsonResp = Portal.Models.JsonWrapper.JsonGET(jsonReq);
        List<Portal.Models.BProcSecurityStructs.Role> listRoles = Models.DeserialiseFromJson<List<Portal.Models.BProcSecurityStructs.Role>>.Deserialise(jsonResp);
        List<GetAllDropdownModel> RolesModelList = new List<GetAllDropdownModel>();
        foreach (BProcSecurityStructs.Role r in listRoles)
        {
            GetAllDropdownModel rm = new GetAllDropdownModel();           
            rm.roleID = r.roleID;
            rm.roleName = r.roleName;
            RolesModelList.Add(rm);
        }
        listRoles.Count();
        ViewBag.List = listRoles;
        return View(RolesModelList);
    }
    }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group" >
   <label for="ddlroles">Roles :</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="listbox" id="dllroles">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <option value="@item.roleId">
      @item.roleName
      </option>

   }
   </select>
</div>
```

Ajax call that am trying to call WCF API

```
  Ajax call that am trying to make WCF API call

    var API_URL = 'http://localhost:50000/Administration.svc/';
    function LoadAdministrator()
    {  
    $.ajax({
    url: API_URL + 'GetAdministratorByID/{loggedID}/{roleId}',
    Type: 'Get',
    DataType: 'jason',
    crossDomain: true,
    sucess: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#ddlroles").append('<Option value= "' + dat[i].roleId + '">"' + data[i].roleName + '"</Option>').text("-- Select --")
        }
    }
});
}
```

**Error:**
  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.    Origin

I have tried this [Code Project Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call)  with no luck. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load your data Ajax, Simply create new Action that return JsonResult

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult SearchReports()
    {

        string jsonReq = "http://localhost:50000/Administration.svc/GetAllRoles/17d7b719-7524-4297-a20d-6a6260966aad/true";
        string jsonResp = Portal.Models.JsonWrapper.JsonGET(jsonReq);
        List<Portal.Models.BProcSecurityStructs.Role> listRoles = Models.DeserialiseFromJson<List<Portal.Models.BProcSecurityStructs.Role>>.Deserialise(jsonResp);
        List<GetAllDropdownModel> RolesModelList = new List<GetAllDropdownModel>();
        foreach (BProcSecurityStructs.Role r in listRoles)
        {
            GetAllDropdownModel rm = new GetAllDropdownModel();
            rm.roleID = r.roleID;
            rm.roleName = r.roleName;
            RolesModelList.Add(rm);
        }

        return Json(yourList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then Invoke this Action Using Ajax

```
function LoadAdministrator()
{ 
   $.ajax({
        url: 'Controller/CancelApplication',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#ddlroles").append('<Option value= "' + dat[i].roleId + '">"' + data[i].roleName + '"</Option>').text("-- Select --")
    }
        }
    });
}
```

That's it, I am always trying to find simplest solutions to my problem not hardest.

Comment: @Ahmed..I am getting this error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

Comment: @MrJunior you invoke your own API from Ajax.. right ? I am taking about controller and action not WCF

Comment: Yes. I have called my Controller and the action. Now am getting this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @MrJunior change the URL to your URL, I just gave you the Idea, replace Controller with your Controller Name and tell me the result

Comment: No it is not working at all. am getting this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53***' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: @MrJunior try to add this in your Controller 
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]

Comment: Or in web.config 

     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>

Comment: but my controller is not an  API it is just a controller? is it fine? I will have to write more functions on this controller afterwards

Comment: Show me where i can allows crossDomain on config? and which URL must it be?  WCF API ?

Comment: The problem not in WCF, it is in Ajax request .. right .. it is not hit your Action in first place .. right ? if yes .. could you please try Ajax request using this way (i update my answer)

Comment: yes. The problem is the Ajax call as it is not even hitting the the controller

Comment: what is the name of your controller, name of your action (that return Jsonresult) and where did you put this Ajax Call (in a View or .js file ) .. provide me with alll this !!!

Comment: SearchReports name of the Controller and my action is SearchReports. I have placed it on js and refferenced it on my view and call the function

Comment: @MrJunior I create Controller with the same name and Action and it working well .. side question .. do you have any errors in console ??? and I am expecting that you load Jquery .. right ?

Comment: I have no error on my console. I think it might be cross domain issue on from the client beacuse i haven't added them. Can you please show me where to add it and how i can do it..either on my controller or config. which ever way you think its the best way

Comment: If you are calling Action from js file in same solution, no need for cross domain. cross domain when you hit url from another domin, I was using it when Hit web service from Mobile App for example.

Comment: I have added this  $.support.cors = true; but still its not working

Comment: @MrJunior did you change your Ajax call by my code as your code has typo error DataType: 'jason',  should by  DataType: 'json', or dataType: 'jsonp',

Comment: didn't get it...send me yours i will invite you

Comment: I am still stuck with one problem and i can't continue.Are you  there?